# What are the differences between in .fsx, .fsi and .fs file in F#?

Tags: f#

So I'm starting to learn F# from the tryfsharp.org and I'm using VS2013. What are the differences of the `.fs` (source), `.fsx` (script) and `.fsi` (signature)?

Comment: Sure the fsi is for interface.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`.fsx` is for individual files intended to run as a script. In particular, in an `.fsx` file you can use things like `#r "Foo.dll"` to dynamically load a library and `#load "Foo.fsx"` to load another script file.
[Edit: and starting with .NET 5, `#r "nuget: FooBar"` to load a NuGet package.]

`.fs` is for source files compiled as part of a project.

`.fsi` is for signature files, they are optional and describe the API of a corresponding `.fs` file. More detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233196.aspx).